# Why does this line of code work for one .CSV but not the others?

Tags: model, distribution, dimension

I am creating a species distribution model with 6 species, and I am consequently trying to model each of them individually. I initially used all 6 species occurrence points in a .csv file to plot a model and test my code, and everything worked absolutely fine.

However, when I try to use individual species in their own dataset, I receive the following error code when I get to extracting climatic variables:

```
Error in data.frame(lon = pres$ï..lon, lat = pres$lat, Nid_bc) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 409, 4
```

(`ï..lon` is my column name, think there might have been an encoding problem when saving the file).

What I am aiming to do is extract the climatic variables at specific `lon` and `lat` occurrence points of each species, and as I said this has not been an issue with the file containing all 6 species occurrences.

I know there is an issue with dimensions, but columns for both individual species and collective points are `lon`, `lat` and `species`, so I can't see why this has become a problem.

I thought there could be a problem matching each variable within the variables dataset to an occurrence point, and have explored many ways around but can't seem to fix it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Have tried transposing dataset to specific dimensions but to no avail.

```
Dimensions for Nid_bc = 4 19 
Dimensions for pres = 409 1 
Dimensions for Bclim dataset = 240 240 19
```

Extract the values for each of the 19 Bioclim variables for occurrence points in study area:

```
Nid_bc = extract(BClim, c(2,-8, 50,60))
```

Do the same for background points:

```
bg_bc = extract(BClim, bg)
```

Builds a dataframe for presence points and 19 climate variables. Consist of 2 columns for coordinates and 19 variables.

```
Nid_bc = data.frame(lon=pres$ï..lon, lat=pres$lat, Nid_bc)
```